# Glassfish Keystore error when creating a mysql datasource in AWS RDS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Can someone help me solve this problem, I just installed glassfish 5.0 in EC2, unzipped the files, changed the master password and admin password, ran the domain, but when I try to create a datasource to a Mysql RDS instance it gave this error

Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]

[image]

I tried a lot of things, made a new domain, used the default master pass, etc, but I'm unable to find an answer for this,.

**New Info:**

I managed to connect removing ssl wit useSSL = false property, but can someone explain how to set up SSL to glassfish in order to conect to RDS winth SSL to me or tell me where can I read abou it.

**Glassfish log**

**SEVERE**

Complete Message

Mon Aug 20 23:36:32 UTC 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

**WARNING**

Message ID test.connection.pool.failed

Complete Message

RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [DB ], Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]

**SEVERE**

Message ID

RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE. endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=DB}'

Thank you

Comment: To allow other users find your question please write the error message as text rather than a picture.

Comment: Ok thank you, I added more information to the question.